# Generate all possible combinations of a function call using Bash script

Tags: bash, function, shell, logic

I have a source file which contains code written in Bash. The source file has some functions defined in it like

```
 - abc(i,j,k)
```

I need to read the source file using a shell script and need to generate all possible combinations of function calls like:

### Output

```
 - abc(i,j,k)
 - abc(i,j,)
 - abc(i,,j)
 - abc(,j,k)
 - abc(,,k)
 - abc(i,,)
 - abc(,j,)
 - abc(,,)
```

For three arguments there are 8 combinations and therefore the combinations will increase or decrease based on the number of arguments.

Comment: In order to answer this question, I need to know which language is being discussed. Which shell scripting language is this question about?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I am using Bash

Comment: Is part of the problem to figure out what functions are defined in the source file?

Comment: @VaughnCato- I have already figured out the solution for finding the functions defined in the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a shorter version. I add pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) soltution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# extract arguments to $arg
fnc=" - abc(i,j,k)"
pre=${fnc%%(*}
post=${fnc##*)}
arg=${fnc#*(}
arg=${arg%)*}

# put arguments to arr array
IFS=, read -a arr <<<"$arg"
num=${#arr[@]}

# Generate all output lines
for((i=0; i<1<<num; ++i));{
  tmp=()
  for ((j=0; j<num; ++j));{
    if ((i & (1<<j))); then tmp[j]=""
    else tmp[j]=${arr[j]}
    fi
  }
  printf -v tmp ,%s "${tmp[@]}"
  echo "$pre("${tmp:1}")$post"
}
```

Output:

```
 - abc(i,j,k)
 - abc(,j,k)
 - abc(i,,k)
 - abc(,,k)
 - abc(i,j,)
 - abc(,j,)
 - abc(i,,)
 - abc(,,)
```

The script uses variable `fnc` as input. The it separated to three parts: pre, args, post. The `arg`s are arrayized. Then it produces the output for each possible variations.

Comment: Thanks a lot..This is what I wanted. I was messing in the inner for loop.

Comment: @vishy: In the inner loop it decodes the number `i` as a binary number. If a bit is 1 the variable replaced by an empty string, if it is 0 then the variable is presented.

Answer (score 4):

bash's brace expansion can generate combinations:

```
printf -- "- abc(%s}\n" {i,},{j,},{k,}
```

But I assume you want it a bit more dynamic than that. This is ugly looking code, but it works.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # match a line that looks like a function,
    # and capture the function name and the parameter list
    if [[ $line =~ " - "([[:alnum:]]+)\(([a-z,]+)\) ]]; then
        funcname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        # split the comma-separated parameters into an array
        IFS=, read -ra params <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        # create the brace-expansion string
        printf -v combos "{%s,}," "${params[@]}"
        # and this is the command to print out the combinations
        cmd=( printf -- "\"- $funcname(%s)\n\"" ${combos%,} )
        # now evaluate it
        eval "${cmd[@]}"
    fi
done <<END
 - abc(i,j,k)
END
```

```
- abc(i,j,k)
- abc(i,j,)
- abc(i,,k)
- abc(i,,)
- abc(,j,k)
- abc(,j,)
- abc(,,k)
- abc(,,)
```

Comment: Nice! Minor comment: using the built-in `printf -v combos ...` spares one `fork` as it fills the variable immediately.

Comment: @TrueY .. Can you tell me whether there is any alternative to printf command?

Comment: @vishy, you could use echo, but why do you not want printf?

Comment: @glenn We cant use echo in replacement of printf -v. Right??  As Printf command forks a process which in case can be overload in high load scenario. Also printf command is not supported in older version of bash.

Comment: I have access to a system with bash 2.03, and it has printf as a builtin (but not printf -v). You could fall back to: `combos=""; for param in "${params[@]}"; do combos="${combos}{${param},},"; done`

Comment: @vishy: glenn already answered. In my version it is `tmp="${tmp},${param}";